# How to select one from duplicates based on a column

Tags: sqlite, group-by, duplicates

```
Code    Category    Name    Type
1       Beverage    Coke    Local
1       Beverage    Coke    Master
2       Beverage    Sprite  Local
3       Beverage    Royal   Master
0       Beverage    Soda    Local
0       Beverage    Coke    Local
```

I want to select unique values based on Code, Category and Name.  If there is a duplicate entry (like element 1 and 2 from the table), i want to keep the 2nd element where the Type = Master.  How can I do this in using SELECT in SQLite?  My current SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name LIKE ? AND category LIKE ? AND code LIKE ?
```

But this will contain duplicates.  Using GROUP BY should eliminate the duplicate but I don't know how to select the TYPE = Master specifically.

Comment: i am using cordova sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite 3.7.11 or later, you can [use MAX() or MIN() to select rows from a group](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bareagg).
"Master" comes after "Local" in the alphabet, so you can use MAX():

```
SELECT Code,
       Category,
       Name,
       MAX(Type)
FROM MyTable
WHERE ...
GROUP BY Code, Category, Name;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was wondering if I have a 3rd value for Type that is equal to "Remote".  Is there an easy way to select Type = "Master"?

Comment: Yes, with a [CASE expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case).

Answer (score 1):

As "Master" > "Local", you can use the MAX function to return the larger of the two values:

```
SELECT Code, category, Name, MAX(Type)
FROM table
WHERE Name LIKE ? AND category LIKE ? AND code LIKE ?
```